# Angular keydown directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I haven't found a solution for this problem. I need to by pressing the spacebar do some actions with the selected item. All solutions were made ​​using input. Any idea how to improve this code? For example don't use jQuery?

Directive:

```
 app.directive('space', function () {
        return function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            $('body').keydown(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 32) {
                    console.log(e);
                    // Actions with data
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Html:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="ReceiptCtrl" space>
    // My page
</div>
```

Ok. I need highlight element by clicking and then in any part of my page by keydown spacebar do something with highlighted element. ng-keydown, ng-keypress and etc. not want to work. Code that i wrote above work fine but it's look awful, I think.

Comment: you can use `angular.element('element')` or even `document.body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elm.onkeydown = function(e)
{    
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
        // Do some actions
};
```